# PHP json_encode add a 1 to the end of the string

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I'm using json_encode throughout my project without issue, except in one instance.

I make an ajax call from one page, as I do in others, and the resulting json appends a 1 to the end of the string for some odd reason.

My return string looks like this

```
{
"overtime": "yes"
}1
```

What could be causing this?  I have literally commented everything out of the class that returns this string and I simply have the following code.

```
$reservation = ['overtime' => 'yes'];
return json_encode($reservation, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

My ajax request looks like this

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "{{ URL::action('Controllers\\PurchasesController@calculateReservation') }}",
        data: { 'arrive' : arrive, 'depart' : depart},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response) {
            alert(response);
        }
    });
```

The alert doesn't fire and doesn't display anything as the json is invalid with the 1 appended to the end of the string.

Comment: In my experience, I normally `echo` a response, rather than `return` it. Try doing that and if necessary, calling `die()` immediately afterwards. Does that help?

Comment: Wow. Yes, that did the trick, thank you!  Very odd as I simply return the json_encode throughout the rest of my project without any issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should `echo` the response from your controller, rather than returning it:

```
echo json_encode($reservation, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

In some scenarios (for example using WordPress), it is also necessary to call `die()` afterwards, as well.

Comment: In my case I was getting a 0 at the end of my ``json_encode`` because I forgot to call ``die()``